HTML form custom validation via setCustomValidity / reportValidity is called only once
I have form with 2 inputs. At least one is required. I want to use setCustomValidity(message) function on form submit. This works but once the message is displayed it never goes away and validateInputs function is never called again thus preventing me from submitting form even if I fill the input!


function validateInputs(event) {
  console.log('validateInputs');
  event.preventDefault();
  const input1 = document.getElementById('input1');
  const input2 = document.getElementById('input2');
  // Check if at least one input is empty
  if (input1.value.trim() === '' && input2.value.trim() === '') {
    input1.setCustomValidity('At least one input is required.');
  } else {
    input1.setCustomValidity('');
  }
  input1.reportValidity();
}

const myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
myForm.addEventListener('submit', validateInputs);
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" id="input1" placeholder="Input 1">
  <input type="text" id="input2" placeholder="Input 2">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>



